# Invalid character constant Â£ (after import from Netbeans to Eclipse IDE)

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, encoding

I've just imported a code file from my Netbeans project into an Eclipse project.  Eclipse does not like the following line of code that was imported:

```
if( value == 'Â£' ) {
```

In Netbeans this shows as:

```
    if( value == '£' ) {
```

I think it might be down to encoding.  Netbeans has a setting for Encoding in Project Properties which is set to UTF-8.  Is there an equivalent setting in Eclipse to get round this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look if the encodings settings of the ide and the files match. i guess that you created the files latin encoding and opened it in eclipse as utf - 8. Or the conversion uses the wrong character set .

In eclipse Preferences go to Edit and File encoding.

Comment: Andeas - works for me.  Bit narly having to do it for each file you want to edit though.  I was hoping there would be a default project setting for it.

Comment: There is you have File, global, and project settings. Right Click on the project to access the settings for the project